# IIS url rewrite need help in outbound for dtd

Tags: c#, iis-8, dtd

I have an issue that needs to be resolved. My WCF server, written in C# code, validates an XML file upon loading. In the XML, there is a DTD URL pointing to an external source to validate the XML against the DTD file.

My requirement is to redirect the outbound request to my locally stored DTD without changing the code, even though the code is already in production. I have looked into
URL Rewrite but have had no luck in finding the right solution. Can anybody help here?

Comment: URL rewriting does not handle external requests from your code, so that's typical misunderstanding of how it works. To solve the original issue you face though, hack `hosts` file on that machine to emulate the domain name, and set up a web server/site to serve the copy of your DTD file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the DNS resolution for the external URL to resolve to your local machine instead of the actual external server. You can achieve this by modifying the hosts file on the server machine. The hosts file is typically located at `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Add an entry mapping the external URL to your local machine's IP address.

Place the DTD file that your XML file references in a location accessible from your local machine. Ensure that when your WCF server attempts to validate the XML file, it resolves the external DTD URL to your local machine and successfully fetches the DTD file from there.